# What mechanism do safety belts use to engage?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, mechanisms

Earlier today I came across a creep testing machine that uses a safety belt as a mechanism for stopping loads from hitting the ground. It is probably the first time I saw a safety belt roll outside of a car and it got me wondering how do safety belts work?

What is the primary mechanism that they are using for engaging and disengaging? I expect it to be entirely mechanical in nature, however I can't put my finger on it.

Is it at all similar to the ratchet or the freewheel mechanism?

Comment: "centrifugal clutch" there are some weights that fling outwards and engage in some teeth when the reel spins too fast

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Might as well make that an answer.

Comment: I'm on mobile so formatting something nice with a picture etc seemed too much effort. I like my answers to always be high quality so just bunged the info in a comment to help out any other people with more time to answer well 

Comment: I'll wait until you post then :-)

Comment: @JonathanRSwift  But you still have power to do winkies!

Comment: One has *more* emoji power when on mobile 